# Trying to make a reload delay in c# yet running into a bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I have been trying to make a game recently and I have ran into a unexpected bug.

As I run the script I have wrote I can shoot 10 bullets out of my gun, then it plays a reload sound and waits two seconds using coroutines and it adds 1200 to my clip for no reason? So I added the if statement telling it that if the clip size goes over 10 then revert it to 10 but now it goes to 19 for a few seconds then back to 10.

I am unaware if I am being a idiot or something but would be glad for some help, also sorry if this is a duplicate but i was unable to find anything similar in c#.

EDIT: i have fixed the bug now, thanks for the help, ill share the new code after the old code for future reference!

**My old code:**

```
{
public float fireRate = 10;
public float damage = 15;
public int clipsize;

float timeUntilFire = 0;
public float ReloadSpeed = 2.5f;
float reloadtime;

public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bullet;
public AudioSource gunshotaudio;
public AudioSource ReloadSound;

void Awake()
{
    gunshotaudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    clipsize = 10;

}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    // if the button pressed is fire 1 and 
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && clipsize != 0)
    {
        timeUntilFire = Time.time / fireRate;
        gunshotaudio.Play();
        Shoot();
        clipsize -= 1;
        Debug.Log(clipsize);
    }
    if(clipsize <= 0)
    {
        ReloadSound.Play();
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
        StopCoroutine(Wait());

    }
    if(clipsize >= 11)
    {
        clipsize = 10;
    }

}

IEnumerator Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);
    clipsize += 10;

}

void Shoot()
{
    gunshotaudio.Play();
    Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position,firePoint.rotation);
}
```

}
** My New Code: **

```
{
public float fireRate = 10;
public float damage = 15;
public int clipsize;

float timeUntilFire = 0;
public float ReloadSpeed = 2.5f;
float reloadtime;
bool CanShoot;
bool IsReloading;
bool reloading;


public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject bullet;
public AudioSource gunshotaudio;
public AudioSource ReloadSound;

void Awake()
{
    gunshotaudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    clipsize = 10;

}
void Start()
{
    if (clipsize > 0)
    {
        CanShoot = true;
    }
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{


    // if the button pressed is fire 1 and 
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && clipsize != 0)
    {
        timeUntilFire = Time.time + fireRate;
        gunshotaudio.Play();
        Shoot();
        clipsize--;
        Debug.Log(clipsize);

    }
    // reloading
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        IsReloading = true;
        ReloadSound.Play();
    }

    if (IsReloading)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait());
    }


}

IEnumerator Wait()
{
    if(reloading == false)
    {
        if (IsReloading)
        {
            reloading = true;
            CanShoot = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            clipsize = 10;
            IsReloading = false;
            Debug.Log(clipsize);
            CanShoot = true;
            reloading = false;
        }

        else
        {

        }
    }

}

void Shoot()
{
    gunshotaudio.Play();
    Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position,firePoint.rotation);
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to add a check if the character is reloading and only perform the reload if he isn't, I am also unsure if `StopCoroutine` is needed.

Comment: [This](https://forum.unity.com/threads/gun-reloading-ammo-and-clips.510335/) might help

Comment: so i did some tinkering and when i shoot i attempt to reload and shoot it adds 129 bullets to my clip then 618 then 1217?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking to see if a reload is already in process, so you are queuing up a bunch of reload events which all add +10 to the clip resulting in extras.

Add a `reloading` bool and check that before you initiate your coroutine and instead of adding 10 to the clip, set the clip to 10.

Comment: could you give a example please?